# How to get top 5 highest CPU consuming processes and their thread count using powershell command

Tags: cpu, powershell, process, threads

How to get top 5 highest CPU consuming processes and their thread count using powershell command?

Need values of CPU, ProcessName, PID, Thread count

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -Desc | Select-Object ID, Name, CPU, @{Name='ThreadCount';Expression ={$_.Threads.Count}} -First 5

   Id Name              CPU ThreadCount
   -- ----              --- -----------
    4 System    12803.21875         276
 6616 sqlservr 11645.328125          63
 1736 dwm       10635.78125          14
 5648 msedge    9159.609375          17
16216 msedge     8914.96875          13
```